# JSP Search Function Using Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I want to add update function in my JSP. I have added all the functions such as add, delete, update all the function are working perfectly. Included search function, but when I click search function, if  data is found in the database that does not show in the JSP page. The else part is showing. Can any one please help to solve the problem? I have added code below.

```
<% 
    if (request.getAttribute("dName") != null) {
        out.println("Your query is Found");
        String dName = (String) request.getAttribute("dName");
        String dId = (String) request.getAttribute("dId");

        out.println("Department Name:" + dName);
        out.println("Department Id:" + dId);    

        request.setAttribute("dName", null);
        request.setAttribute("dId", null);
    } else {
        out.flush();
        out.println("dhfdhfj");
    }
%>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting "dName" attribute?

Comment: provide your html code. check dName is correct or not

Comment: You should use serlvets (or classes) for Java code and tags (and EL) instead of `out`.

Comment: I have found the solutions, I am passing dId as integer from the servlet. anyway thnx,

Comment: Its bad programming practice .@Bhesh Gurung suggestion is best.Always avoid java code over JSP.

Comment: can you please convert it to EL ,

Answer (score 0):

Changed to

```
 Integer dId = (Integer) request.getAttribute("dId");
```

Comment: May be your code will work work. But you should always avoid java code on JSP.